# Hyperlink to "hidden" content (a certain #id) inside a jQuery-Toggler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is how to be able to link to a certain content (e.g. a certain `id` (i.c.: `#link`), that is inside a *jQuery*-"Toggler", like the one I have shown below:

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".toggler").click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow")
        }).next().hide();
    });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.toggler {
    color:orange;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin-top:0px
}
.toggler:hover {
    color:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none
}
div#toggled {
    background-color:light-green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>I would like to have <a href="#link">a link</a> here, with a destination inside the Toggler.
<br>
<br>
<hr>
<p class="toggler">Toggle here.</p>
<div id="toggled">Imagine I would like to have the <span id="link" style="color:red">link-destination <i>(id="link")</i></span> inside this Toggled content (the difficulty is successfully arriving here when the Toggler is closed).</div>
<hr>
```

So, the problem arises only when the Toggler is closed/hidden, then the link can not arrive anywhere.

What would be needed for this is an automatic opener for the Toggler I guess, so some way of checking whether the link occurs inside the Toggler first. Or is there perhaps a much easier way around this?

Would someone give me any help on how to go about this?

---

***Edit:*** In my specific case, and as a general utility; it might be handy to be able to work with multiple such hyperlinks and/or multiple such Togglers.

What would be the best (to save manual work when having tons of links and toggles, especially in a *working* document), is to automatically look up the link-destination and his parent Toggler, and then automatically open that `toggled`, as with `.fadeIn("fast");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fadeIn()` function on click on the link to open up the toggler and the link will automatically do its job.

JavaScript:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".toggler").click(function(){
          $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        }).next().hide();
        $(".togglerLink").click(function(){
           $(this).nextAll('.toggled:first').fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Here's the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dk8uhh4y/1/

P.S. I have given an `id` to the link and added more content in the HTML before & after the `<span id="link"></span>` to properly depict the scenario.

Comment: Smart, very similar to the actual Toggler-function. --- But, like with the previous answer, I just frighten the work of manually adding *jQuery* for every link (as in `("#theLink-foo").click....` Since I have tons of links and Togglers, all named `toggler`. It would be nice to look up the link-destination and his parent Toggler, and then automatically use your `.fadeIn("fast");` on that toggled. --- Very smooth answer however, thanks.

Comment: To make it generic make use of `classes` instead of `ids`.
Next using the function `nextAll()`, we can get the siblings of the link & select the first instance with `:first` selector....I have tried to update the code for the same

Comment: This is a great automated answer, thanks a lot. --- However great this is working in JSFiddle, on my site the **links can't automatically** open the Togglers, even though the *Togglers themselves still work fine*, and the *links works fine as well, when the Togglers are opened manually* ... Thanks for any ideas on that issue.

Comment: User [T.S.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226267/t-s) has just debugged that issue via the follow-up question [jQuery-line → $(this).nextAll('.toggled:first') ← works in Stack Snippet and JSFiddle, but not on site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526651/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#link" id="actualLink">a link</a>
```

then:

```
$('#actualLink').click(function(e){
  $('.toggler')[0].click(); // click the toggler..
  location.hash = e.target.href;
});
```

That should work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9fkcbqvh/

Comment: Wow, thanks! That works great! --- However I haven't found a way to then easily work with multiple links and multiple Togglers. --- Might I ask you: how does your code know what Toggler needs to be clicked? And in `$('.toggler')[0].click();`, is `[0]` some entry of an array? --- Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$('.toggler')` is a jQuery object, the `[0]` returns the first HTML element that matches the query selector, so in this instance, the first element with class "toggler", I am calling the `.click()` function on the HTML element because that will actually simulate a mouse click and trigger any click-events added with jQuery.

Comment: You might want to add some code to check if the toggler is already showing, because if it clicks the toggler and hides it, it won't work, didn't think of that

Comment: You're right, that would be vital. --- Thanks a lot for your adept explanation. --- How would you go about when having 2 different links, both linking to that same `.toggler`? Since you can only use `id="actualLink"` once? --- And as for different `.toggler`'s, then would you suggest it might be handy to rename your `.toggler-foo`'s up front, so that you can reference to them more easily?

Comment: you would only have to change the id's of the <a>'s when referencing the same toggler, when using multiple togglers i would suggest keeping the classnames as is, but adding an id to each toggler as well.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to [user1726659](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726659)'s automated answer:

Taking his code as a baseline, one can change

- `$(".togglerLink").click(function(){`

to

- `$("a[href^=#]").click(function(){`

, so then the `class="togglerLink"` inside the `<a class="togglerLink" href="#link">`-links isn't needed any more.

---

So then `$("a[href^=#]")` looks for the links with a destination that starts with a hashtag (`#`).

One can read more about this in the [jQuery-API entry for ***Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]***](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).